# How do I test if all the variables are present inside the settings?

Tags: pytest, fastapi

I am working with Fastapi and I would like to include a test to check if all settings variables exist in the env file (which currently goes to read directly into the pipeline), I would like it not to create the container (last step) if it doesn't pass the tests, but it happens that the tests pass and I end up with an environment variable not set or forgotten.
I use the .env file to retrieve the variables

My setting file (I removed some variables so as not to paste in too much stuff, fields could not match, some I made up):

```py
class Settings(BaseSettings):
    app_name: str
    kafka_broker: str
    healthcheck_topic: str = "_healthcheck"

    # Apicurio
    apicurio_uri: str
    apicurio_journal_topic: str = "kafkasql-journal"

    business_rules_topic: str = "_message"

    jwt_secret: str
    jwt_expiration_sec: int = 24 * 60 * 60  # A day
    _jwt_algorithm: str = PrivateAttr(default_factory=lambda: "HS256")

    admin_username: str
    admin_password: str

    azure_auth_url: str
 
    class Config:
        try:
            env_file = '.env'
            env_file_encoding = 'utf-8'
            case_sensitive = False
        except:
            env_file = '.env_local'
            env_file_encoding = 'utf-8'
            case_sensitive = False


    def __init__(self, **data):
        super().__init__(**data)

        self._postgresql_conn = make_url(self.postgresql_conn_url)

    @property
    def postgresql_conn(self) -> URL:
        return self._postgresql_conn

    @property
    def jwt_algorithm(self) -> str:
        return self._jwt_algorithm


    @validator('redis_user', 'redis_password')
    def field_is_not_empty_if_not_null(cls, v):
        if v is not None and len(v) == 0:
            raise ValueError("Field cannot be empty string")

        return v

    _fields_not_empty = validator(
        'kafka_broker',
        'app_name',
        'apicurio_journal_topic',
        'business_rules_topic',
        'jwt_secret',
        allow_reuse=True
    )(field_not_empty)

    _fields_are_positive = validator(
        'cache_short_expiration_hours',
        'cache_medium_expiration_hours',
        'cache_long_expiration_hours',
        'jwt_expiration_sec',
        allow_reuse=True
    )(field_non_zero_positive)

    _fields_are_uri = validator(
        'apicurio_uri',
        'ticket_uri',
        allow_reuse=True
    )(field_is_uri)

    def build_api_definition(self) -> TicketApiDefinition:
        return TicketApiDefinition(

            webservice_endpoint=self.ticket_webservice_path,
            webservice_path=self.ticket_webservice_path,

            create_session=self.ticket_webservice_create_session_endpoint,

        )


@lru_cache
def get_settings():
    return Settings()
```

At the moment I wrote this simple test, but maybe it is not enough:

```py
from gateway_api.settings import get_settings
from gateway_api.settings import Settings


def test_00_check_env_variables():
    sett = get_settings()
    assert isinstance(sett, Settings)
```

Do you have any advice for me? Or is this test sufficient?

Thank you

Comment: You're gonna have to share more code than that. What type of object is `Settings`? If it's a subclass of [pydantic's `BaseSettings`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/settings/), and you don't have default values, then something along the lines of your test should work, since the class won't instantiate unless all variables are set.

Comment: You can use specific pydantic types to avoid having to manually create validators; see https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/types/#urls and https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/types/#constrained-types (`PositiveInt`, `conint`); use `Optional` or `constr` to disallow None or an empty string (i.e. have a minimum length of 1 with `min_length=1`).